# Etymological Origin of 'Glome?'

Tags: general-topology, terminology

The glome is $S^3$. All I have found is that it is Latin for 'ball of string.' Can anyone refer me to the etymology?

Comment: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/glomus#Latin

Comment: Is there any mathematical context attached to this?

Comment: Not that I know of.

Answer (score 2):

The English word is indeed from Latin *glomus* ‘a ball of yarn’. The Latin word appears to derive from the Proto-Indo-European root **gel-* ‘to curl, to form into a ball’; the same root (with a different extension) underlies Latin *globus* ‘a round body, a ball, a sphere, a globe; a throng; a clump’ and Latin *glaeba* ~ *glēba* ‘a lump of earth, a clod; a lump or mass of stuff’, and probably English *clump* and a host of related Germanic words, e.g., Old Norse *kleppr* ‘a plummet, a lump’. The etymological information [here](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/glomus#Etymology_2) appears to be reasonably sound.

Comment: I've seen visual representations of the 3-sphere (e.g. the Hopf fibration - OP, if you're interested see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopf_fibration)) which to me at least resemble a ball of yarn; do you know if there's a connection here, or is this just a coincidence?

Comment: @Noah: I really don’t know. I’d have guessed that someone just latched onto the *ball, clump, lump* notion and wanted a fancy, Latinate word, but if the person who came up with the term had the necessary Latin background, there certainly could have been more to it. (By the way, James R. Wells used the term in his science fiction novel *The Great Symmetry* for ‘[a] naturally occurring hypersphere that allows near-instant travel between star systems’.)